# Performance with sequentially increasing primary key

Tags: performance, database-design, primary-key

Looking for guidance on selecting a database provider for a specific key pattern.

The only key field will be a pre-allocated unique sequentially-increasing number. 
During each day between
50 and 100 thousand items will be added,
processed (updated), and then retained for a week or so, 
after which usually the lowest-numbered records will be deleted. The number of 
records will not fluctuate by very much from day to day but may drop at weekends.
The numbers will probably wrap back to 1 after 100M or so.

I need to find a database implementation where the efficiency of the index lookup,
addition and deletion remains constant.  Should I be worried that the performance might drop off as the key value range moves continuously upwards?

Comment: You should probably re-title this to indicate that you're interested in performance/fragmentation/indexing rather than appearing to want to know if you can get sequential primary keys...

Comment: are the records added by a single process, or do you have to deal with contention between processes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> index lookup, addition and deletion remains constant

You could ensure it remains constant by rebuilding the indexes every insert (just constantly really slow - no performance drop off at all :)), or close to constant by running index maintenance every hour/day etc.

> that the performance might drop off as the key value range moves continuously upwards?

As long as you've got an index, it should be logN performance - e.g. having 1,000,000 rows will be around half the speed of 1,000 rows (when searching for an indexed value).  (1,000,000,000,000 will be half that speed again).

So no, you shouldn't need to worry about performance.

> The numbers will probably wrap back to 1 after 100M or so.

Ok - if you want.  Generally, no need really - just use a big int.

As always with performance: test what you want to do.  Make a script that inserts 10,000,000 rows, and see what happens.

My point here being that if you're going to wrap ids at 100M records, the worst you can do  is actually have them all allocated.  This would represent the fragmented index condition as well (where you only have say 100K records, but they're distributed in a space of 10M)  - but you *will* do index/database maintenance right?

Comment: The only thing I have to add is that over time this table will suffer from heavy fragmentation, but that has nothing to do with IDs per se. A once in a while OPTIMIZE TABLE command would fix things up (though locking the table for writes in MySQL at least).

Comment: Yep - pretty much any system that allocates resources out of a finite space requires defragmentation at some stage.  File systems, databases, the memory your program uses... this is why all these systems have maintenance/defragmentation plans of one sort or another

Comment: @Artem Russakovskii: "this table will suffer from heavy fragmentation" - over time ANY table having a large no. of inserts will experience fragmentation; that's why yoiu should rebuild indexes as often as is possible.